# No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: python

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and have problems when try to import the tkinter module. I've tried installing with python3-tkinter but apparently does not work.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`?

Comment: @kapil Yes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` failed? Or do you mean that it did not solve your problem?

Comment: It works with pyhton 2. import Tkinter. But it doesn't work in python3.